# checkbox form control value is false but displayed true

Tags: angular

I have a form control that recieves its value in my initForm method. 
'Record' is an input and I recieve the right value on ngOnInit - it is false by default.
the problem is that my checkbox 'lock' is checked even if the value is false.
I don't understand why is this happening

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
    console.log(this.record.lock)
  }

initForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
    lock: [
              {value: this.record.lock}]
        });
}

  get lock(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get('lock');
  }

 <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mr-0 pretty p-svg p-curve">
              <input type="checkbox" id="lock-vendor-booth" 
                     formControlName="lock"/>
              <div class="state p-danger">
                  <label>Lock</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the group like this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  lock: [this.record.lock]
});
```

I created a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formcontrol-checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the form control as below

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    lock: new FormControl(this.record.lock, []);
}
```